# package misses files -- how to fix package?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, dpkg

I have `Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS` installed on one the machines. I used to experiment with other kernels (currently it boots with 4.15.0 built manually from the sources), so somehow I damaged the package `linux-image-4.15.0-13-generic` which came along with the distro. In particular, /lib/modules/4.15.0-13-generic/* is missing as well as some files in /boot directory. So my question is how do I fix this broken package, is it sufficient to remove it first (`apt-get remove` or `apt autoremove --purge` and then re-install again)? I'm being extra careful, because I don't want to ruin the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already tried simply reinstalling it?

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-4.15.0-13-generic
```

That should not damage the system.